# Scrapy crawler is scraping only one item, not all

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I am trying to scrape items starting with A from [this page](https://www.rozee.pk/jobs-by-industry) using following code.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from ..items import RozeepkItem
class JobcatsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'jobcats'
    allowed_domains = ['www.rozee.pk']
    start_urls = ['https://www.rozee.pk/jobs-by-industry']

    

    def parse(self, response):
        items = RozeepkItem()
        for job_cat in Selector(response).xpath("//div[@class = 'boxb job-dtl sitemap']"):
            category_title =  job_cat.xpath(".//div[@id = 'A-block']/div[@class = 'row']/ul/li/a/@title").get()
            url = job_cat.xpath(".//div[@id = 'A-block']/div[@class = 'row']/ul/li/a/@href").get()

            items['job_category'] = category_title
            items['url_str'] = url

            yield items
```

following is `items.py`

```
import scrapy
class RozeepkItem(scrapy.Item):
    job_category = scrapy.Field()
    url_str = scrapy.Field()
```

it gives output

```
2020-06-27 06:55:00 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.rozee.pk/jobs-by-industry>
{'job_category': 'Accounting Jobs in Pakistan',
 'url_str': '//www.rozee.pk/search/accounting-jobs-in-pakistan'}
2020-06-27 06:55:00 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2020-06-27 06:55:00 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 232,
 'downloader/request_count': 1,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 16977,
 'downloader/response_count': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 2.227556,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 6, 27, 1, 55, 0, 379725),
 'item_scraped_count': 1,
 'log_count/DEBUG': 2,
 'log_count/INFO': 10,
 'response_received_count': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 6, 27, 1, 54, 58, 152169)}
2020-06-27 06:55:00 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

As it can be seen I am only getting one item and its corresponding link, on the other hand if i try this xpath in browser I get all the information as it can be seen in following screenshot.

[image: xpath screenshot]

Can some help me that where I am making mistake? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the doc :

> .get() always returns a single result; if there are several matches,
> content of a first match is returned; if there are no matches, None is
> returned. .getall() returns a list with all results.

So, use `.getall()` in your code not `get()`.